# Check selector is exist or not in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Right now i have some role user and each role will have some different when creating account
So i have create condition to check that the dropdown is exist or not

'''

```
  if(await t.expect(this.dynamicButtonDropdownByAttribute('originator-org-select-button').exists).ok()){
    await this.selectValueInDropdownByAttribute('originator-org-select-button' , 'ORG')
    await this.clickButtonByAttribute('originator-org-next-button')
  }
```

'''

that is ok when dropdown is existed but when not existed, it still run code in if condition, so i'm not sure why it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

`expect` doesn't return the result of an assertion; it returns `testController`. Thanks to it, you can run actions in a chain. So, you need to remove `expect` from the condition like this:

```js
if(await this.dynamicButtonDropdownByAttribute('originator-org-select-button').exists){
    await this.selectValueInDropdownByAttribute('originator-org-select-button' , 'ORG')
    await this.clickButtonByAttribute('originator-org-next-button')
}
```